# Power BI Rounds Numbers Automatically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following DAX in Power BI:

```
NOTIONAL USD = DIVIDE(TABLE[POSITION] * TABLE[UNIT], 1000000.00)
```

For one of the rows, I get the following value 8.184 as Position is 8184, Unit is 1000.

However, if I try add an addition, it just becomes 8.000 and is rounded. I've tried the following, the all end up with 8.000.

```
NOTIONAL USD = DIVIDE(TABLE[POSITION] * TABLE[UNIT], 1000000.00) + 0.00

NOTIONAL USD = DIVIDE(TABLE[POSITION] * TABLE[UNIT], 1000000.00) + 0.01
```

Why does Power BI do this?

FYI I use DirectQuery.

Comment: Can you share some input data ? expected output ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.